# Text-align:center and margin:0 auto not working on absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I'm trying to align a div in the center, but neither text-align: center, nor margin: 0 auto, seems to work on the absolute positioned element. I'm assuming neither works on absolute positioned elements. In this case, what should I do instead?

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#absolute {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='absolute'>Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing the HTML, the easiest approach to center the element horizontally would be to combine `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)`. This will essentially position the element `50%` to the right and then displace half of the element's width by transforming it `-50%` to the left. In doing so, the element will be centered horizontally regardless of the width which means that you don't need to hardcode any values.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Updated Snippet:

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
}
#absolute {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="absolute">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you can change the HTML, simply add `left: 0` and `right: 0` to the absolutely positioned element element in order for it to take the width of the parent container. Then you can add `text-align: center` in order to center the child element:

Updated Snippet:

```css
#wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
}
#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#absolute > span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="absolute">
    <span>Click Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioned elements just love to be different from everyone else, huh? Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the size of the wrapper, you can just add `left: 250px` (half the wrapper size) to the css of your absolutely positioned element.

Comment: The above is actually just an example. I do not actually know the size of the wrapper. It's declared in percentages.